# How to end drawing a path and start creating a completely new one from the last point of previous one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here is what I have in my project:

[image]

I need to merge them into one object, as it is on the image. But ones I add another point to the current path it ends with rounding last section of the path, what is not expected for me:

[image]

How can I do this in Photoshop?

I would like to make it rather like this, but using one single Path, not two separated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the **end anchor point** on the existing path with the **Pen Tool** to continue with the same path.

If you want to continue the path *without* a smooth point, then hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down when you click.

Review the [**Help Files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html) for basic Pen Tool operations.